# Image upload function not working Nodejs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs/Expressjs, I am working with Rest API, I am creating Rest api with following format

```
const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
const firstparam = req.params.firstname;
const secondparam = req.params.secondname;
try {
        await User.functionName(firstparam,secondparam);

        return res.status(202).send({
            statusCode: 202,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            statusCode: 500,
        });
    }
};
module.exports = {
    updateUser,
    upload-avatar,
};
```

Above function is working fine but whenever i try to create function for image uploading then not working, giving me error "not defined",Where i am wrong ?

```
app.post('/upload-avatar', upload.single('dataFile'), (req, res, next) => {
   const file = req.file;
   if (!file) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Please upload a file.' });
   }
   var sql = INSERT QUERY;
   var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
       return res.send({ message: 'File is successfully.', file });
    });
});
```

Comment: Share the error